# Where is error?

Tags: c++, excel

I writed program to convert a number of cell and row to excel data. Here is code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
char dgt[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
int input = 10;
int output = 26;
int main() {
char name[64];
std::cin.getline(name, 64);
string text = name;
char* temp;
int spacja = text.find(' ');
long liczba = strtol(text.substr(spacja+1,text.size()).c_str(), &temp, input);
string out = "";
liczba--;
for (int i = 32; true; i--) {
    out = dgt[liczba % output - (i==32?0:1)] + out;
    liczba = liczba / output;
    if (liczba <= 0)
        break;
}
cout  <<  out << text.substr(0,spacja);
return 0;
}
```

I got 90/100, in one test it's return bad value. Where is error? I cannot check it.

Comment: Your pointer doesn't point anywhere (in particular). You also forgot to include `<string>`.

Comment: What does this code do? Try to pay more when writing questions so you might get more when getting answers..

Comment: This code convert a number of column to number of column in excel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this using:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
char dgt[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
int input = 10;
int output = 26;
string convert(long liczba) {
string out = "";
liczba--;
for (int i = 32; true; i--) {
    char add = dgt[liczba % output - (i==32?0:1)];
    if(add==0) {
        add='Z';
        out =  add + out;
        liczba = liczba / output-1;
    } else {
        out =  add + out;
        liczba = liczba / output;
    }
    if (liczba <= 0)
        break;
}
return out;
}
int main() {
char name[64];
std::cin.getline(name, 64);
string text = name;
char* temp;
int spacja = text.find(' ');
long liczba = strtol(text.substr(spacja+1,text.size()).c_str(), &temp, input);
cout  <<  convert(liczba) << text.substr(0,spacja);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First, there is no reason for `dgt` to be declared as a C-style character array:

```
std::string dgt = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
```

Second, you should use `std::getline` instead of `cin.getline`:

```
std::string line;
std::getline(cin, line);
```

Third, you should use `std::stol` instead of `strtol`:

```
std::string s = "123";
long liczba = std::stol(s);
```

The problem you are seeing right now is due to the fact that you've declared

```
char* temp; // an uninitialized pointer
```

And then you attempt to use it

```
long liczba = strtol(text.substr(spacja+1,text.size()).c_str(), &temp, input);
//                                                              ^^^^^ This will result in a runtime error
```

Using `std::stol` avoids that issue.

To do #2 and #3, you need to include `<string>`.

Comment: Nice explanation. It seems like I also do similar mistakes. Where does it write that we should use std::getline and std::stol. It might be nice to see others.

Comment: @phoad It isn't so much written down somewhere as you should select the correct too for the correct job (in a similar way that you use a hammer to pound a nail, and a screwdriver to twist a screw).  `std::getline(std::ostream&, std::string&)` already uses `std::string`, so there is no reason to convert to and from a C-style character array.  The same goes for `std::stol`.  The C++11 standard addressed the issues of the stream and string libraries being developed in parallel in previous versions of the standard by making sure they worked together in this version of the standard.

Comment: I don't have any exception. I have bad return. I solved this: if I type 702, I got A Z (A\nZ). Thank you for council, but your solution don't resolved this.

Comment: @barwnikk I didn't say that would fix your mysterious error (as you never said what the error was).  But each of those issues is a problem in your code (and still a problem in your "fixed" code).

Comment: I'm sorry, but I must do this in a website, where I must send code and server test this (there are about 1000 exercises). This is polish server: zadania.oig.edu.pl. This exercise got 90/100 points (on 10 tests, 1 test ends with failure).

Comment: @ZacHowland, I meant the new functions, using std::stol instead of strtol. So they come with C++11. Thank you.